# Openindiana oi_151a5 zpool ashift=12 "devices have different sector alignment" issue on a raid1

Tags: zfs, openindiana

i am desperate from some help. Currently at my job i inherited a NAS system which a former admin before me build with OpenIndiana oi_151a5 on a ZFS filesystem. the problem is, one of the SSD drives is in a failed state and is part of the logs partition. it is part of a raid1 setup for it think the /tank2 zpool. We bought replacement SSDs (Intel SSDSC2BB120G401 serial) however when i go to do a zpool replace, it errors out with "devices have different sector alignment". have found some documentation from these links:

zpool command bug:
    .......................
    https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/ZFS+and+Advanced+Format+disks
    https://wiki.uiowa.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=109796051
    https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/566
    .......................

however the fix that they recommend seems to either blow away the zpool, or download the patched binary zpool-12 - which i did, and just gives the same error as the normal zpool command.

this is the stats on the drives i am trying to replace:

```
*************

[Dead HDD]
c6::w55cd2e404bd0a454,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client     Device: /dev/dsk/c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0s0(sd18)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,340e@7/pci1028,1f1c@0/iport@f0:scsi::w55cd2e404bd0a454,0

[Still working HDD raid1 Mirror]
c6::w55cd2e404bd06fa3,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c2t55CD2E404BD06FA3d0s0(sd17)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,340e@7/pci1028,1f1c@0/iport@f0:scsi::w55cd2e404bd06fa3,0

***********
```

and this is the new drives i am trying to fail over too.

```
***********
root@:/kernel/drv# iostat -Er | grep -i vendor | sort | uniq
Vendor: ATA      ,Product: INTEL SSDSC2BB12 ,Revision: 0370 ,Serial No: PHWL707603WJ120 
Vendor: ATA      ,Product: INTEL SSDSC2BB12 ,Revision: 0370 ,Serial No:     PHWL710300CE120 
***********
```

this is the command that i have been using:

```
zpool replace -f tank2 c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0 -o ashift=12
```

and the same for the zpool-12 command...

here is the output from the bash shell

```
..........................................
root@:/osadmin/scripts# zpool replace -f tank2 c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0         c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0 -o ashift=12
too many arguments
usage:
    replace [-f] <pool> <device> [new-device]
root@:/osadmin/scripts# zpool replace -f tank2 c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0
cannot replace c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 with c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0: devices have different sector alignment

......
root@:/osadmin/scripts# sudo ./zpool-12 replace -f tank2 c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0
cannot replace c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 with c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0: devices have different sector alignment
root@:/osadmin/scripts# sudo ./zpool-12 replace -f logs c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0
cannot open 'logs': no such pool
root@:/osadmin/scripts# sudo ./zpool-12 replace -f tank2 c2t55CD2E404BD0A454d0 c2t55CD2E414D6B29B1d0 -o ashift=12
too many arguments
usage:
    replace [-f] <pool> <device> [new-device]
root@:/osadmin/scripts# 
........................................
```

does anyone know if it would be possible to take out the SSD drives, put them in a laptop, and boot to a liveCD of OpenIndiana and then try to force a re-sectoring of the SDDs? would that even work after the power to the laptop is shut off?

unfortunately this system that is currently having the issues, is a live production system.

any advice would be helpful thank you

Comment: Can you post your zpool status? I'm confused as to the actual build of the pool. You can do: zpool status tank2

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i actually got it fixed by useing two old hard drives, as apposed to the solid state drives i was trying to put into the array.